# Kubernetes Java API does not use username password supplied

Tags: java, kubernetes

This is in regards to version 0.2 of the Kubernetes Java client. I'm guessing the way to use basic authentication in the Java API is to do this

```
ApiClient client = Config.fromUserPassword( "https://....:6443", "user", "password", false );
Configuration.setDefaultApiClient( client );
CoreV1Api api = new CoreV1Api();
// Make api call like
api.listNode(...)
```

However the above code always returns 403 Forbidden. From the response message, it doesn't look like the user/pass is being used in the request.

```
{"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"nodes is forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot list nodes at the cluster scope","reason":"Forbidden","details":{"kind":"nodes"},"code":403}
```

I also debugged through the code a bit and I may be answering my own question but it looks like in CoreV1Api's methods, it never add basic auth as an authentication method and only uses BearerToken. Is basic auth supported or should I be using another API class?

Comment: The Kubernestes Dashboard only provides option to either enter Kubeconfig or Bearer Token. It does not give option to enter username/password.

Comment: My use case isn't only the Kubernetes Dashboard but writing an external Java client to get information about the nodes, clusters etc. The Java client I'm referring to is here https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/

Comment: I was just providing FYI that dashboard does not use basic auth too, which might mean that there are no support for basic auth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question but it doesn't look like the current version of the client actually executes the user/pass authentication. BearerToken is working however.

Answer (score 0):

Many kubernetes clusters do not set up basic auth, only bearer token auth. Are you sure your cluster configured basic authentication?

https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authentication/#static-password-file

Comment: Yes I've configured the apiserver with --basic-auth-file=.... The file seems to read correctly otherwise the apiserver wouldn't start if suppose I put in the wrong path.

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

The java client ignores the `HttpBasicAuth` object, but if you use the `ApiKeyAuth` object and set the key prefix to "Basic" and the API key to the base64 encoded credentials, it will work.

For example:

`String credentials= new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode("user:password".getBytes()));
ApiClient  defaultClient = Configuration.getDefaultApiClient();
defaultClient.setBasePath("https://256.256.256.256");
ApiKeyAuth fakeBearerToken = (ApiKeyAuth) defaultClient.getAuthentication("BearerToken");
fakeBearerToken.setApiKey(credentials);
fakeBearerToken.setApiKeyPrefix("Basic");`

This works because the kubernetes client will simply concatenate the API key prefix with the prefix, and put the result in the "Authorization" header.